# Confusion about AngularJS Dependencies

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, namespaces

I have a project that's become too big for monolithic controller/service files so I've started to break them into smaller components and then use the module/dependency injection system to keep everything working.

I'm having a little trouble understanding exactly what Angular does with dependencies because I'm finding things working in modules even when I haven't declared a dependency. Here's a quick example:

```js
// a simpler app that uses 2 controllers
angular.module("myApp", ["controller", "controller2"]);

// controller has a dependency on 
// module1 to access the constant

angular.module("controller", ["module1"])
.controller("newController", ["$scope", "mod1Constant", function ($scope, mod1Constant) {
 $scope.myText1 = mod1Constant; 
}]);

// controller2 doesn't declare a dependency 
// on module1 but can still access the constant

angular.module("controller2", [])
.controller("newController2", ["$scope", "mod1Constant", function ($scope, mod1Constant) {
 $scope.myText2 = mod1Constant; 
}]);


angular.module("module1", [])
.constant("mod1Constant", "module 1 constant");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="newController">
  {{myText1}}
</div>
<div ng-controller="newController2">
  {{myText2}}
</div>


</div>
```

**My question is basically: why does `controller2` work?**

At no point is `module1` injected into `controller2`, but it seems that the controller is able to access the namespace.

It seems that by injecting the module anywhere you are able to access it everywhere, which makes me wonder what the point of the modules are. Is dependency injection more like dumping all dependencies into  shared bucket rather that building a tree of dependencies? or am I missing something real basic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. In Angular, once you injected a module into a parent module, all of its services are available everywhere in that parent module. I agree that this is not a very modular behavior, and one of the pain points Angular 1.

In Angular 2 (currently in beta), this has been somewhat improved, and you have to specify for each `Component`, what services will be [injected](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html#!#dependency-injection) into it.

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer. It inspired me to weigh the option of getting started with Angular 2. Went to the documentation and see that it's all documented in Typescript, which I will need to learn before I can even understand the primer. That kind of took the wind out of my sails.

Comment: You don't have to use Typescript (and you can change the documentation to JS), but I actually like it. Maybe because I like Java :)

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but if all the documentation is in Typescript, it's going to be a lot easier to learn with it. I'm reading an Typsecript primer now. It looks pretty nice and not especially hard.

Answer (score 1):

I just added some more code, which will help you in understanding better!!!

Constants are available in configuration phase, before parent modules are injected into main module, which is applicable to parent modules as well.

Controllers will be instantiated after configuration phase, hence constants are available to parent controller.

**Life cycle:**
child module constants---->parent Module1 constants------------->parent Module2 constants
----->  parent Module3 constants----->parent Module1 controllers ------>parent Module2 controllers -------->parent Module3 controllers-------->child module controllers

constants are created before controllers , so you're able to use them in parent controllers

**from console:**

myApp constant

module1 constant

controller:module 1 constant

controller2:module 1 constant

controller3:myApp module constant

myAppController:myApp module constant

```js
// a simpler app that uses 3 controllers
angular.module("myApp", ["controller", "controller2","controller3"]);


angular.module("myApp").constant('myAppConstant',{'name':'myApp module constant','log':console.log('myApp constant')});

angular.module('myApp').controller('myAppController',['$scope','myAppConstant',function($scope,myAppConstant){
  console.log('myAppController:'+myAppConstant.name);
  $scope.myText = myAppConstant.name; 
}]);



// controller has a dependency on 
// module1 to access the constant

angular.module("controller", ["module1"])
.controller("newController", ["$scope", "mod1Constant", function ($scope, mod1Constant) {
  console.log('controller:'+mod1Constant.name);
 $scope.myText1 = mod1Constant.name; 
}]);

// controller2 doesn't declare a dependency 
// on module1 but can still access the constant

angular.module("controller2", [])
.controller("newController2", ["$scope", "mod1Constant", function ($scope, mod1Constant) {
  console.log('controller2:'+mod1Constant.name);
 $scope.myText2 = mod1Constant.name; 
}]);



angular.module("controller3", [])
.controller("newController3", ["$scope","myAppConstant", function ($scope,myAppConstant) {
  console.log('controller3:'+myAppConstant.name);
 $scope.myText3 = myAppConstant.name; 
}]);




angular.module("module1", [])
.constant("mod1Constant", {'name':"module 1 constant",'log':console.log('module1 constant')});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="newController">
  {{myText1}}
</div>
<div ng-controller="newController2">
  {{myText2}}
</div>

 <div ng-controller="newController3">
  {{myText3}}
</div>

  <div ng-controller="myAppController">
  {{myText}}
</div>

</div>
```